# Why does my translation not work & how can I fix it?

Tags: php

I'm struggling with a translation in the footer navigation. the translation for the navigation works fine but I can't figure out how to set the translation for text_1 & text_2. I would appreciate any help a lot!

This is my PHP for the language:

```
<?php

class l
{
public static function lang($name)
{
$l = array();
// Footer
$l['text_1'] = "Hello";
$l['text_2'] = "World";

return $l[$name];
}

public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments)
{
return self::lang($name);
}
}

?>
```

And this is what I try to translate (text_1 & text_2):

```
<?php

class footer_nav
{

public function get_footer_nav()
{

$lang = language::getLang();

if (isset($_GET['page']))
  $page = $_GET['page'];
else
  $page = 'home';


$ret = '
        <a href="' . $lang . '/private" ';
if ($page == 'private')
  $ret .= ('class="active"');
$ret .= '>' . l::confidence() . '</a>
        <a href="' . $lang . '/rules" ';
if ($page == 'rules')
  $ret .= ('class="active"');
$ret .= '>' . l::rules() . '</a>
        <a href="' . $lang . '/reklama" ';
if ($page == 'reklama')
  $ret .= ('class="active"');
$ret .= '>' . l::adv() . '</a>
        <a href="' . $lang . '/contact" ';
if ($page == 'contact')
  $ret .= ('class="active"');
$ret .= '>' . l::contacts() . '</a>
    ';


return $ret;

<div class="soc_box">
    <a href="#" target="_blank" class="facebook_ico"></a>
    <a href="#" target="_blank" class="twitter_ico"></a>
        <p class="soc_box_txt">
            ' . l::text_1() . '<br />
            ' . l::text_2() . '
        </p>
 </div>

 }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: I don't know if accidental but your <div> is inside the php tags.

Comment: @GabCas You're right it doesn't belong there but right know I don't know where else to put it. I moved it under the php tags but still get an error message. My php skills are not good and I'm a little bit lost here..:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take the divs out of the Php code like this:

```
?>
<div class="soc_box">
    <a href="#" target="_blank" class="facebook_ico"></a>
    <a href="#" target="_blank" class="twitter_ico"></a>
        <p class="soc_box_txt">
            ' . l::text_1() . '<br />
            ' . l::text_2() . '
        </p>
 </div>
<?php
```

Just close php code with *?>* add html code and start php code again with *< ?php* or:

```
echo '<div class="soc_box">';
 echo '<a href="#" target="_blank" class="facebook_ico"></a>';
 echo '<a href="#" target="_blank" class="twitter_ico"></a>';
 echo '<p class="soc_box_txt">
            \' . l::text_1() . \'<br />
            \' . l::text_2() . \'
       </p>';
 echo ' </div>';
```

Comment: I did it but get ' . l::text_1() . ' & ' . l::text_2() . ' as a result. Without the whole <div> the translation of my footer_nav works fine. Do you know why my translation for the <div> doesn't work?

Comment: Try adding the return line after the divs are drawn.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong: php; ?> <div></div> <?php return $ret; }} ?> With this I don't get an error but the whole page setup gets messed up and the <div> doesn't show at all...

Comment: I forgot you were doing this for the footer. Is the footer just links or should the divs be included? Append to the return value the divs and then return $ret

Comment: You lost me... I showed the code of the footer nav in the above section. They're links with translation - which are working fine. I didn't understand what to do now - could please open it up for me?

Comment: if the divs are not needed for the footer, just remove them from the function. If they are, append them to $ret as you do with the other links.  ie: $ret .= '<a href="#" target="_blank" class="facebook_ico"></a>'; etc.